# Failed to load API definition error in magento 2 swagger

Tags: magento2, swagger, swaggerui

I am hitting magento 2 swagger UI but getting 500 error 
Failed to load API definition

http://'website_name'.com/swagger/

Answer (score 5):

Please check the network error in the browser if you have something like :

**message: "The "array" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again."**

it can be related to this issue https://github.com/mundipagg/magento2/issues/137

Answer (score 3):

If you have created custom Magento 2 Rest API, you have to document the API properly ie mention the DOC BLOCK in the interface. Also, you need to verify the return type and input parameter should match the DOC.

For example :

```
/**
 * Get Register Otp.
 *
 * @param int $mobileNumber
 * @return int
 * @since 101.0.0
 */
public function getRegisterOtp($mobileNumber);
```

Comment: great; but somebody knows if there's some way to get a list of the methods with docblock missing?